# How to refactor and move sub-packages along with the outermost package?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

There is an outermost package and then a number of many sub-  and sub-sub packages in an existing open-source project.

Eg: `com.example.android.outer` and then `com.example.android.outer.inner1;` `com.example.android.outer.inner2` ...

I am trying to move the whole outermost & all its sub-packages down the hierarchy, from that project to another new one. There are like few hundred files and more than 50 sub and sub-sub packages. Following are the issues that I am encountering:

**1)** If I am refactoring(or copying) the outermost package, only the files which are in outermost package are getting moved.

**2)** If I am just copying the files, then there are issues with the `.R` import. The R file that was generated in the previous project remains( import com.example.android.outer.R; ) and gives errors in the new project. Since I have 100's of files, manually removing the import line from each of them it is a pain.

How can I refactor the package and its sub and sub-sub ... packages down the hierarchy at once? I tried to search but could find any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move (refactor) the packages one by one. It is a one-time task, you can do it in less than one hour, just go ahead with that.

Honestly, Eclipse will take care about everything, you don't have to worry. You would waste more time with finding and fixing bugs if you are copying and trying to fix it manually, compared to the time you spend on manually moving packages.

Last but not least, you'll lose your source control history with copying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.You are right. I have already tried copying. I got fed up. What I did was, instead of refactoring the whole android project and all the packages separately, I declared the old project as a library and created a reference of it from my current project.